Migration Bundle Logs not being sent to Seq
When executing migration bundles logs are not sent to Seq. When executing the application normally everything is neatly sent to Seq.
First I assumed it was because Log.CloseAndFlush() was not called, because I had previously troubles with that, that's why I migrated to the minimal hosting model, now I get the last log "Stopped web application" but logs are still not sent to seq when running migration bundles.
Program.cs:
// truncated ...

IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(directoryName)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(environment))
{
    configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
}

configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables(EnvPrefix);

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom
    .Configuration(configurationBuilder.Build())
    .CreateLogger();

Console.WriteLine("Created bootstrapping logger");

try
{
    Log.Information("Bootstrapping web application");

    WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddSerilog(logger => logger.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration));

    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

    builder.Services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(
        options => options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db")!,
        options => options.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(SomeDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name))
    );

    // truncated ...

    Log.Information("Building web application");

    WebApplication app = builder.Build();
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

    // truncated ...

    Log.Information("Starting web application");

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60600
    if (exception.GetType().Name.Equals("StopTheHostException", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        throw;
    }

    Log.Fatal(exception, "Unhandled exception was caught: {Message}", exception.Message);
}
finally
{
    Log.Information("Stopped web application");

    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}

appsettings.json:
{
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": [
            "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
            "Serilog.Sinks.Seq",
            "Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo"
        ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Information"
        },
        "Enrich": [
            {"Name": "FromLogContext"},
            {"Name": "WithCorrelationId", "Args": {"headerName": "x-correlation-id", "addValueIfHeaderAbsence": true}}
        ],
        "Properties": {
            "Application": "app-name"
        },
        "WriteTo": [
            {"Name": "Console"},
            {"Name": "Seq", "Args": {"serverUrl": "http://your-seq-url"}}
        ]
    }
    // truncated ...
}

At this point I have no Idea why the logs might not be sent to Seq and I am on the brink of scrapping migration bundles. This only happens using efc migration bundles, everything works fine when running normally.

I found a workaround.
When using migration bundles just adapt your appsettings*.json to use AuditTo instead of WriteTo and then the logs will be sent without needing to call Log.CloseAndFlush()
{
    "Serilog": {
    // truncated ...
        "AuditTo": [
            {"Name": "Console"},
            {"Name": "Seq", "Args": {"serverUrl": "http://your-seq-url"}}
        ]
    }
    // truncated ...
}


Note: Keep in mind using this during normal application run will have performance problems.
